# Is it possible to have progress bar for file uploads when using REST API?

Tags: php, rest, file-upload

I use `base64` encoding for file uploads. The `REST API` is as below for file uploads:

```
POST /users/:resourceid/files
```

Authentications are handled through `resourceid`. And the content of the `POST` request is files content in `base64` format.

Can I have progress bar for my file uploads? If no, then which path should I take to handle file uploads with progress bar?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this,

```
request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e){
    _progress.style.width = Math.ceil(e.loaded/e.total) * 100 + '%';
}, false);
```

Full explanation [here](http://codular.com/javascript-ajax-file-upload-with-progress).

Comment: How's that possible when all of the file is sent in a big chunk with `base64` encode via REST API? Did you have the same issue with `REST API` or this is just a general article for upload a file with progress bar. As far as I know `REST` is `stateless`. thanks

Comment: when using RESTful style in HTTP then you may use anything that HTTP supports.